# How to select a file as part of VS Code extension configuration?

Tags: configuration, vscode-extensions

As part of the configuration of my VS Code extension, the user should be able to select a text file (actually a script for gvpr). Potential selections are included in the extension, but user-provided files should be possible.

I fail to see how file selection is supported by the [configuration contribution points](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#contributes.configuration). So how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no specific `type` for files/folder path, unfortunately.

You should use `”type”: “string”` instead, and maybe combine with `“pattern”`, applying some regex to validate the path structure.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your help. There really seems to be no better solution at the moment. I created a [feature request](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/160539).